# restore backup database with out sql server management studio

Tags: sql

I have one database backup.

Now  i want to install this backup to my friend's system.

His system does not contain SQL Server Management Studio.

How can i install my backup to his system, both are using SQL server 2005.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<s>**Statement 1:** *His system does not contain SQL server management studio*</s>

**Statement 2:** *both are using SQL server 2005...*

Doesn't the above two statements **Contradict** each other?

**Update** Please Ignore my Previous Answer

Run the following Command on Command Promt:

```
SqlCmd -E -S MyServer –Q “RESTORE DATABASE [MyDB] 
       FROM DISK=’D:BackupsMyDB.bak(Your backup Databse file)’”
```

I got the [refrence from here](http://www.howtogeek.com/50295/backup-your-sql-server-database-from-the-command-line/)

Comment: installing Management studio is *optional*. And there are installers available in microsoft that contains only servers and nothing else `:)`

Comment: No, those two do **not** contradict each other. SQL Server Management Studio is something completely different than SQL Server 2005 (SSMS is a *client* application used to *access* a running SQL Server installation).

Comment: You still claim that those two statements contradict each other, which they still don't

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name can you please edit my answer. Actually i want to use a cross line(I don't what is the way to do it. Right i am going through FAQ. But no positive.).

Comment: No shortcut, just (html) tags: <s> ... </s>

Answer (score 0):

You will need *some* kind of SQL client on the other computer. As `sqlcmd` is part of any SQL Server installation that can be used.

Then use the `RESTORE` (SQL) statement to restore the backup.

Details about the `RESTORE` statement can be found in the manual: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms190372%28v=sql.90%29.aspx

You can use **any** SQL client that is able to connect to the SQL Server on the second computer to run that.

To make things easier, you could use *your* SSMS instance to let it *generate* the necessary SQL statement. Just pretend to restore the backup on your computer and use the "Generate Script" dropdown at the top of the dialog to see the SQL that would have been run by SSMS.